# Unrecognized environment error in TeXstudio

Tags: environments, texstudio, feynman

I've created a document in Overleaf in which I code some Feynmann diagrams, using the `feynmp` package. I create them with the following structure:

```
\begin{fmffile}{W1}
\begin{fmfgraph*}(40,25)
% Diagram
\end{fmfgraph*}
\end{fmffile}
```

However, when I copy the document and paste it in TeXstudio, everything but the diagram works fine, the document compiles but the diagram doesn't show, and the command `\begin{fmffile}` returns the error

> Unrecognized environment

Could you help me out? Thanks.

Comment: As always you are much more likely to get help if you provide a full but minimal exmaple others can copy and test as is. Here we have to add document class, preamble etc in order to even test your code. Please ease the testing process.

Comment: Welcome. // This checklist can help you to turn your code fragment into a MWE we'd like to see here: https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/a/10137/245790

Comment: `Unrecognized environment` is not a latex error, what gives the error, just yoru syntax highlighting, or do you get an error when you run latex?